# MySQL SELECT query with conditions

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table which looks something like:

```
id batch_id start_ts stop_ts
```

I want to select those ids which started yesterday (can be easily done by giving start_ts > .. AND start_ts < ..) and have another id in the table with the same batch_id as the batch_id of this id and that id ended yesterday.

What would be a good way to frame this MySQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about ...

```
select <field list>  
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.id = t2.batch_id
where start_ts between <date 1> and <date 2>
```